# Invalid Hook Call when using useSelector in Functional Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks

I get the error

> Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component.
>
> 1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
> 2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
> 3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app

Which I do not understand. I am using `useSelector()` throughout my App without any Problems. And when using it in this component, it breaks. Why is that?

```
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";

const DrawerContent = (props) => {
  const someVar = useSelector((state) => state.foo.bar);
  return (
    <DrawerContentScrollView {...props}>
      <Foo>{someVar}</Foo>
      <DrawerItemList {...props}>
        <DrawerItem
          label="Kitten"
          onPress={() => props.navigation.navigate("Cat")}
        />
        <DrawerItem
          label="Doggo"
          onPress={() => props.navigation.navigate("Dog")}
        />
      </DrawerItemList>
    </DrawerContentScrollView>
  );
};
```

`<DrawerContent />` is used like this

```
const DrawerNavigator = () => {
    return <Drawer.Navigator
        drawerContent={props => DrawerContent(props)}>
        <Drawer.Screen name='A' component={TabNavigator} />
        <Drawer.Screen name='B' component={AStack} />
        <Drawer.Screen name='C' component={BStack} />
    </Drawer.Navigator>
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to import React?

Comment: I usually do this: useSelector(state => state.reduceUser.userName)

Comment: @James That (`menuComponent={props => <MainMenu {...props}/>`) is actually what I have.

Comment: @Stophface How is `DrawerContent` rendered (assuming that's where you got the error from)? How is it's parent rendered and it's parent ... If you render a functional component by calling it's function outside the render cycle you may have this error. If you crate this component as re usable separate project that you import then you may have mismatching React versions that can cause this error.

Comment: @HMR as I said, I using hooks all over the App, and they work. So a mismatching `react` version is unlikely I would say. I added how `DrawerComponent` is used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're calling DrawerContent like a normal function, not using it as a tag. As a result, DrawerContent will not have life cycle or state, it's just a normal function, return stuff. You need to invoke it by using JSX syntax, then DrawerContent will have life cycle and you can useSelector there.

```
const DrawerNavigator = () => {
    return <Drawer.Navigator
        drawerContent={props => DrawerContent(props)}>  // This just call DrawerContent as a normal function with no life cycle and state
        <Drawer.Screen name='A' component={TabNavigator} />
        <Drawer.Screen name='B' component={AStack} />
        <Drawer.Screen name='C' component={BStack} />
    </Drawer.Navigator>
}
```

Solution:

```
const DrawerNavigator = () => {
    return <Drawer.Navigator
        drawerContent={props => <DrawerContent {...props} />}>  // Now your component has life cycle
        <Drawer.Screen name='A' component={TabNavigator} />
        <Drawer.Screen name='B' component={AStack} />
        <Drawer.Screen name='C' component={BStack} />
    </Drawer.Navigator>
}
```